# Estimate the standard deviation of fitted parameters in scipy.odr?

Tags: python, scipy, regression

(*Somewhat related to this question [Linear fit including all errors with NumPy/SciPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951876/linear-fit-including-all-errors-with-numpy-scipy), and borrowing code from this one [Linear fitting in python with uncertainty in both x and y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670057/linear-fitting-in-python-with-uncertainty-in-both-x-and-y-coordinates)*)

I fit a linear model (`y=a*x+b`) using fixed errors in `x,y` using [scipy.odr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) (code is below), and I get:

```
Parameters (a, b): [ 5.21806759 -4.08019995]
Standard errors: [ 0.83897588  2.33472161]
Squared diagonal covariance: [ 1.06304228  2.9582588 ]
```

What is the correct standard deviation values for the fitted `a, b` parameters? I'm assuming these must be obtained from the `Squared diagonal covariance` values, but then how are these values related to the `Standard errors`?

**ADD**

As mentioned in the answer to [How to compute standard error from ODR results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028846/how-to-compute-standard-error-from-odr-results) by `ali_m`, this is apparently related to [a bug in scipy.odr](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6842). If one uses

```
np.sqrt(np.diag(out.cov_beta * out.res_var))
```

(i.e: multiply the covariance by the residual variance) instead of just

```
np.sqrt(np.diag(out.cov_beta))
```

the result now coincides with `out.sd_beta`.

So now my question is: which is the proper standard deviation for the fitted parameters `(a, b)`? Is it `out.sd_beta` (equivalently: `np.sqrt(np.diag(out.cov_beta * out.res_var))`) or `np.sqrt(np.diag(out.cov_beta))`?

---

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.odr import Model, RealData, ODR
import random

random.seed(9001)
np.random.seed(117)

def getData(c):
    """Initiate random data."""
    x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    y = np.array([i**2 + random.random() for i in x])
    xerr = c * np.array([random.random() for i in x])
    yerr = c * np.array([random.random() for i in x])
    return x, y, xerr, yerr

def linear_func(p, x):
    """Linear model."""
    a, b = p
    return a * x + b

def fitModel(x, y, xerr, yerr):
    # Create a model for fitting.
    linear_model = Model(linear_func)
    # Create a RealData object using our initiated data from above.
    data = RealData(x, y, sx=xerr, sy=yerr)
    # Set up ODR with the model and data.
    odr = ODR(data, linear_model, beta0=[0., 1.])
    # Run the regression.
    out = odr.run()

    # Estimated parameter values
    beta = out.beta
    print("Parameters (a, b): {}".format(beta))
    # Standard errors of the estimated parameters
    std = out.sd_beta
    print("Standard errors: {}".format(std))
    # Covariance matrix of the estimated parameters
    cov = out.cov_beta
    stddev = np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))
    print("Squared diagonal covariance: {}".format(stddev))


# Generate data and fit the model.
x, y, xerr, yerr = getData(1.)
fitModel(x, y, xerr, yerr)
```

Comment: *"which is the proper standard deviation for the fitted parameters (a, b)? Is it `out.sd_beta` or `np.sqrt(np.diag(out.cov_beta * out.res_var))`?"* These two quantities are equivalent, so I don't really understand your question.

Comment: @ali_m sorry, I messed up, thanks for bringing it to my attention. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `out.sd_beta` contains the standard deviations for the estimated parameters, which are equivalent to the square roots of the diagonal terms in the parameter covariance matrix.

As you've already mentioned above, there's a bug in `scipy.odr` that means you have to multiply `out.cov_beta` by the residual variance `out.res_var` in order to derive the actual covariance matrix for the parameters.

Comment: ali_m, if you have the time, please take a look at this new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040618/standard-deviation-for-fitted-parameters-with-scipy-odr-when-data-contains-erro